# Not able to create funding table for multiple children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

each child can apply for funding. But when I apply for funding it always created funding application for Child_id:1 even if I am applying for some other child. funding belongs to child and children can have many fundings. please help

fundings_controller.rb

```
def create
  @funding = Funding.new(funding_params)

  @funding.child = Child.find(child_user.ids[0])
    if @funding.save
      flash[:success] = "Thankyou for submitting"
      redirect_to funding_path(@funding)
    else 
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= Family.find(session[:family_id]) if session[:family_id]
  end

  def parent_user
  @parent_user ||= Parent.find(session[:family_id]) if session[:family_id]
  end

  def child_user
    puts session[:family_id]
  @child_user ||= Child.where(:parent_id=>session[:family_id]).limit(1) if session[:family_id]
end
```

funding.rb

```
class Funding < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :organisations
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :organisations, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    belongs_to :child
end
```

child.rb

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :parent
    has_many :fundings
    validates :parent_id, presence: true
    validates :firstname, presence: true
    validates :lastname, presence: true
    validates :dateofbirth, presence: true
end
```

parent.rb

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :secondaryparents, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :secondaryparents, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
    belongs_to :family
    validates :parent_1_firstname,   presence: true
    validates :parent_1_lastname,    presence: true
    validates :address,              presence: true
    validates :city,                 presence: true
    validates :telephone_number,     presence: true
    validates :postal_code,          presence: true
    validates :email,                presence: true
    validates :family_id,            presence: true
end
```

family.rb

```
class Family < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :parents, dependent: :destroy

    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Za-z0-9.]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

    has_secure_password

end
```

Parent
_form.html.erb

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @parent %>
<div class='row'>
  <div class= 'col-xs-12'>
    <%= form_for(@parent, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
        <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">

        <%= f.label :parent_1_firstname %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :parent_1_firstname, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Parent 1 first name", autofocus:true %>
      </div>
    </div>

       <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
             <%= f.label :parent_1_lastname %>
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-8">
             <%= f.text_field :parent_1_lastname, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Parent 1 last name", autofocus:true %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p><strong>Add Secondary Parents or Guardians<br /></strong></p>
        <div id ='secondaryparents'>
        <%= f.fields_for :secondaryparents do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'secondaryparent_fields', :f => builder %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Secondary Parent', f, :secondaryparents %>
      </div>



      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :address %>
      </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_area :address, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Address", autofocus:true %>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :city %>
      </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control", placeholder: "City", autofocus:true %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :province %>
    </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :province, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Province", autofocus:true %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :telephone_number %>
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :telephone_number, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Telephone Number", autofocus:true %>
    </div>
    </div>

      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :postal_code %>
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :postal_code, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Postal code", autofocus:true %>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :email, value: current_user.email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email", readonly:true, autofocus:true %>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :family_situation %>
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_area :family_situation, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Family Situation", autofocus:true %>
     </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>

</div>
</div>
```

children
_form.html.erb

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj:@child %>

<div class='row'>
  <div class= 'col-xs-12'>
    <%= form_for(@child, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |form| %>
        <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">

        <%= form.label :firstname %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= form.text_field :firstname, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter child's first name", autofocus:true %>
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
             <%= form.label :lastname %>

           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-8">
             <%= form.text_field :lastname, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter child's last name", autofocus:true %>
          </div>
        </div>


      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= form.label :dateofbirth %>
      </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= form.date_field :dateofbirth, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Date of Birth", autofocus:true %>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= form.label :gender  %>
      </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= form.select :gender, ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Gender", autofocus:true %>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <%= form.submit(@child.new_record? ? "Add your child" : "Update your child ", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg') %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <% end %>
```

funding _form.html.erb

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class= 'col-xs-12'>
    <%= form_for(@funding, :html => {class: "form-horizontal",role: "form"}) do |form| %>

      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :type_of_activity %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.select :type_of_activity, ['Swimming', 'Soccer', 'Cricket', 'Basket Ball'] %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :describe_activity %>
        </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <%= form.text_area :describe_activity %>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :season %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.select :season, ['Fall', 'Winter', 'Summer'], autofocus:true %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :activity_details %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_area :activity_details %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :name_of_organisation %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.select :name_of_organisation, ['BCCI', 'IPL', 'Sahara', 'Not listed'], class: "form-control", autofocus:true %>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div id ='Organisations'>
        <%= form.fields_for :organisations do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'organisation_fields', :form => builder %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Organisation', form, :organisations, form_name: 'form' %>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :activity_start_date %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.date_field :activity_start_date %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :number_of_weeks %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :number_of_weeks %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :days_per_week %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :days_per_week %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :hours_per_day %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :hours_per_day %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :program_registration_cost %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :program_registration_cost %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :family_contribution %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :family_contribution %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :other_funds %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :other_funds %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :other_fund_provider %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :other_fund_provider %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :amount_requested %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :amount_requested %>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :status %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.select :status, ['Pending', 'Approved', 'Declined'], class: "form-control", autofocus:true %>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <%= form.submit "Apply", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <% end %>
```

[image: when I create on apply for funding and then submit the form. the funding for someother child with different child_id gets created]

Comment: @iGian even I think there is a problem here. I want that each child should be able to create its funding. but the problem is, it just gets creates it for child_id:1 even if I am doing for some other child_id

Comment: I suppose it is because `child_user.ids[0]` returns the first element of the array and `ids` I think are ordered in ascending order. Or it is because you are limiting to 1 record on `child_user` definition: `.limit(1)` What is the purpose? Can you post the relevant models?

Comment: @iGian purpose?

Comment: @iGian i dont want the limit. i want the funding should get created for the particular child_id i am creating for.

Comment: What do you mean you don't want the limit? You literally wrote `limit(1)` and you are using `find` which is an implied limit 1 and you are only passing 1 id `child_user.ids[0]` and you are only creating a single funding `Funding.new`. Everything you have posted shows you want this limitation so are you asking to have it all rewritten to allow the creation of multiple fundings for multiple children?

Comment: @engineersmnkyI know it is my mistake. but I am not able to figure out how to remove this limitation so that I can allow the creation of multiple fundings for multiple children

Comment: It seems you would need to pass the child ID as a parameter to your FundingsController#create action.  How does the applicant designate which child they are applying for in the UI?

Comment: I suggest you to use plural in application_controller, just because you are fetching a collection, something like: `current_user_parents` and `current_user_children`. It sounds clearer. I could have an idea to get your goal but I'm missing the relations between the models: `Family` - `Parent` - `User` - `Child`. Maybe there no `User` model, since you are looking in `Family` model to get the `current_user`.

Comment: @iGian I have added the funding, child and parent model above. Please have a look. you are right about the family model which i use to get the current_user

Comment: @engineersmnky it was deleted by mistake. sorry. Can you help me?

Comment: @iGian any help?

Comment: @BillDoughty any help?

Comment: I am still very uncertain what you are trying to do. What is "each child"? When one child applies for funding do all the other children apply as well? what do you mean "even if I am applying for some other child"? I have literally no understanding of your work flow

Comment: @engineersmnky there is a parent and each parent has many children. the parent applies for funding for each child. the funding table has the child_id. when under the create function for funding controller the funding application gets created only for the first child in the table. even if the parent applies for some other child with some id other child_id=1. if i am applying for any child with child_id:2 after submitting it the funding gets created for Child_id:1. this is the issue.

Comment: @Navroop, show us the HTML for your form, the controller action that populates its data, and any Javascript that may be manipulating the POST (create) request before it gets sent, if any.  Like engineersmnky, I still don't understand your desired workflow.

Comment: Should the parent be able to apply for multiple children at once, or just one child at a time?

Comment: @BillDoughty I have added the form for parent, child and funding above. please have a look

Comment: @Navroop, please answer my last question.  I believe parents apply for funding for one child at a time.  Correct?

Comment: @BillDoughty not according to the form parameters. Still not sure I understand at all ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: yes you are right @BillDoughty. one child at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a parent can only apply for funding for one child at a time, let them choose which child in the funding form, and pass in the :child_id as part of the funding parameters to the FundingsController#create action.

fundings_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @funding = Funding.new(funding_params)

  if @funding.save
    flash[:success] = "Thankyou for submitting"
    redirect_to funding_path(@funding)
  else 
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= Family.find(session[:family_id]) if session[:family_id]
end

def parent_user
  @parent_user ||= Parent.find(session[:family_id]) if session[:family_id]
end

def current_children
  puts session[:family_id]
  @current_children ||= Child.where(:parent_id => parent_user.id) if session[:family_id]
end
helper_method :current_children
```

funding_form.html.erb

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class= 'col-xs-12'>
    <%= form_for(@funding, :html => {class: "form-horizontal",role: "form"}) do |form| %>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label(:child_id, "Select child") %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.select :child_id, options_for_select(current_children.map{|c| [c.firstname, c.id]}) %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :type_of_activity %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.select :type_of_activity, ['Swimming', 'Soccer', 'Cricket', 'Basket Ball'] %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :describe_activity %>
        </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <%= form.text_area :describe_activity %>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :season %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.select :season, ['Fall', 'Winter', 'Summer'], autofocus:true %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :activity_details %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_area :activity_details %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :name_of_organisation %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.select :name_of_organisation, ['BCCI', 'IPL', 'Sahara', 'Not listed'], class: "form-control", autofocus:true %>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div id ='Organisations'>
        <%= form.fields_for :organisations do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'organisation_fields', :form => builder %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Organisation', form, :organisations, form_name: 'form' %>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :activity_start_date %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.date_field :activity_start_date %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :number_of_weeks %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :number_of_weeks %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :days_per_week %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :days_per_week %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :hours_per_day %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :hours_per_day %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :program_registration_cost %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :program_registration_cost %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :family_contribution %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :family_contribution %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :other_funds %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :other_funds %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :other_fund_provider %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :other_fund_provider %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :amount_requested %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.text_field :amount_requested %>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class = "form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
          <%= form.label :status %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <%= form.select :status, ['Pending', 'Approved', 'Declined'], class: "form-control", autofocus:true %>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <%= form.submit "Apply", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>    
</div>
```

Comment: You would also need to permit the :child_id parameter in the fundings controller.

Comment: @BillDoughty I tried your solution it works. I have added an image. Isn't it possible that I just click on apply for funding and apply for funding page opens for that particular child?

Comment: @Navroop, yes, but that's not your original question.  Please post a new  question for that and accept my answer for this one if it worked for you.   Thank you.

Comment: @BillDoughty can you help me with the other question?

Comment: Hint: before you post your new question, try adding the child_id as an embedded parameter in the URL for the button.  Then you can read it in the action that you link to.

Comment: @Navroop, sure, just try to get it working yourself, then post your code and any problems, if you encounter any.

Comment: @BillDoughty the code posted above is for this problem. When I click on apply for funding and then submit it. It creates the funding for the child with some other child_id

Comment: I don't understand.  You said it worked.  If you have a new problem, post a new question, but please try to solve it yourself, first.

Comment: @BillDoughty I don't want child select in the form. I just wanted to click on Apply for this child to create funding for it. I said your code worked because your way is also correct but I don't want it that way.

Comment: I answered your original question. Just post a new one on how to embed parameters in a button URL.  We'll answer it for you.  Thank you.

Comment: @BillDoughty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519309/not-able-to-create-funding-table-for-a-particular-child-how-to-embed-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your models, this should be part of the database tables.

```
|Family |Parent    |Child      |Funding   |Organisation  |
|-------+----------+-----------+----------+--------------|
|id     | id       | id        |id        |id            |
|-------+----------+-----------+----------+--------------|
|       |family_id |parent_id  |child_id  |founding_id   |
```

The problem I see is that when you create a new funding you can add just one child. But you got a collection then you limited to 1 to make it work.

But you are adding only the first child fetched for the current_user (`.limit(1)`).

What you should do is for each one of the children, belonging to the parents, belonging to the `current_user` (found in Family), you need to create a new funding.

But the code changes a lot. Removing `.limit(1)` to get all the children collection, scan the collection and create a funding for each children.

But I think you need to create a new action in a different controller for that.

Or, but I do not know your purpose, consider to use a different association, like [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) between `Child` and `Funding`.

Comment: @iGianI have added those associations between child and funding because a child can have more than one funding application for different activities.

Comment: @Navroop, I understand has_and_belongs_to_many does it. Or  you need to choose just one child to add, see the answer from Bill Doughty

Comment: @BillDoughty I tried your solution it works. I have added an image. Isn't it possible that I just click on apply for funding and apply for funding page opens for that particular child?

Comment: @Navroop, if the image you added is `children#show`, you can do that passing the `child_id` param with the link: `<%= link_to "Apply for funding", new_funding_path(child_id: @child.id) %>`. Then instead of select form for child use a hidden field: `<%= hidden_field_tag :child_id, params[:child_id] %>`